# how to create view from a model which is consisted in a dll file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dll file that consists my whole project model, and now I want to use its classes in my asp.net mvc project as model. After adding my dll file to ASP.NET MVC project when I wanted to add view from my model in Controller I couldn't find any classes from dll file.
So after this unsuccessful trying, I create a class which is derived from a class included in dll, and again I added a view based on this new class, again I couldn't have a nice View ( which would have all feature of base class)
so how can I do this challenge?

Comment: Are you talking about not being to bind your view with the `@model` directive?

Comment: @beautifulcoder : i mean i cant scaffold my model beautifully to Views like  Create,List,Edit etc.  by right click on the name of method in a controller and then select Add View  . I mean in this way , after selecting Add View i cant see my model in class Model list ( in Add View window)